# Bootstrap-Full screen background photo/image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a landing page using Bootstrap 3.3.6 Cover template (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/). I am attempting to add a full screen background image. I believe the problem may be I do not have a div class="cover" in my html code. My css code is below:

```
.cover {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what's the rest of your code? that little snippet doesn't really help

Comment: If you believe that the problem is that you don't have the class cover, why don't you add it to your html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right so to create this give your `body` a `width` and `height` of `100%`:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then you need to have an element to apply the background too like a `header`:

```
<header> 
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</header>
```

Then give your header a `background-image`

```
header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/BG.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

You do not have to use header you could create your own class for example called `.full-sceen-bg` and apply that to any section

Hope this helps, Any questions just ask